# Give non-overlapping parts of 2 rasters a value 0 (QGIS)

Tags: qgis, raster, raster-calculator, masking

Is there a way in QGIS to give non-overlapping parts of 2 rasters a value of 0 in the new raster file?

I would like the data gaps in the velocity file (so where Ice mask is displayed on the chart) to be zero in a new raster file, so a new raster with the original value of velocity for pixels that have ice mask = 1 and velocity > 0, else 0.

[image]

Comment: is python an option?

Comment: QGIS raster calculator uses GDAL so I guess yes

Comment: do the rasters have the same extent? are the gaps nodata?

Comment: Both yes. I would like to define a new raster for pixels that have ice mask = 1 and velocity > 0.

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/411526/88814

Answer (score 0):

in pure python this code does what you are asking for:

```
from osgeo import gdal    

ds = gdal.Open(yourotherraster)
band = ds.GetRasterBand(1)
arrA = band.ReadAsArray()
ds = gdal.Open('yourraster')
band = ds.GetRasterBand(1)
arrB = band.ReadAsArray()
arrB = np.where((arrA == 1), 2, arrB) #your condition
[cols, rows] = array.shape
driver = gdal.GetDriverByName("GTiff")
outdata = driver.Create('youroutputraster.tif', rows, cols, 1,
                                    gdal.GDT_UInt16)
outdata.SetGeoTransform(ds.GetGeoTransform())  ##sets same geotransform as input
outdata.SetProjection(ds.GetProjection())  ##sets same projection as input
outdata.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(array)
outdata.GetRasterBand(1).SetNoDataValue(0)  ##if you want these values transparent
outdata.FlushCache()  ##saves to disk!!
outdata = None
band = None
ds = None
i=0
```