# How to make a simple overlay of raster layers in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

I have several raster single-band layers that share a common intersection.

I want to overlay them in a certain order on top of each other in QGIS version 3.34 and save the result as a separate layer ([here](https://disk.yandex.ru/i/jzM1npu6FmtnFg) is an example).

To do this, I tried tools such as Build Virtual Router and Merge - both change the brightness of the resulting image, which is unacceptable in my case.

I need to get an overlay of all the layers without any interference with the pixel values.

How can this be done in QGIS?

Comment: If the pixels appear a bit brigther, that does not mean that pixel values are changed. How the raster appears depends (between else) on min and max settings. However, from your question it becomes not clear how exactly you would like your result to look like. Build virtual raster, then export, is probably what you want... (?)

Comment: I've already tried it, the result is not what I need. I would like to export the current overlayed layers as one single-band layer, without any interference with their values.


It's like in my video: there are 5 layers on the map, I want to convert them into one single-band layer so that it looks exactly like the original layers, overlayed in the specified order.

Comment: "If the pixels appear a bit brigther..."

I wouldn't say that: in my example, the source layers have a maximum pixel value of ~26K (uint16), and the resulting layer already has ~42K (i.e., a brightness increase of more than 60%, which does not correspond "a bit brighter").

Comment: Again: even if the **color** is completely different, that does not mean that the pixel's **value** is changed. Color is party of the style, not the data itself. The problem is rather: if you have overlapping parts, which value do you expect from the output

Comment: Since I have overlapping values on the plot, I want to get the value of this section of the composition, which is at the top layer.

Comment: See here: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/39731 Also be aware if pixels don't perfectly overlap (if one raster's pixels ar shifter a bit).

Comment: Does this help? https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/411526/88814

Comment: Thank you, something else helped:

On the newly created virtual raster layer, right-click, select "Properties" -> "Transparency" -> in the "Additional no data value" field, set the value to 0 and press Enter.

After that, a band stop being distorted.